# How would I do a regular expression for a python function definition with an unknown amount of variables?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get a regular expression that can recognize a python function definition with any number of variables as parameters. So far I have:

```
"def\s[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\("
```

Some examples of what I am looking for are:

```
def a():

def b(c,d,_e1):

def f(g*):

def h(i**):
```

How would I do this? Would one single regex do the trick?

Comment: Why do you need to match the entire function definition header? The prefix up to the `(` (which you already match) works just as well for finding the locations of definitions, and for anything more complex you wouldn't want to use regular expressions anyway. Take a look at the `tokenize` and `ast` modules.

Comment: I was wondering if you could recognize a `def(` then go into a checker for various conditions that come after the `def(`. And if those continue to return true then make sure it ends with `):`. But this seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @delnan - I know how to use both `tokenize` and `ast` the issue is that they don't play nicely together and tokenize.untokenize() is not that dependable.

Comment: @baallezx Why would you use both together? If you want analysis at a token level, use `tokenize`. If you want a syntax tree, use `ast`. Different use cases, hence different modules.

Comment: @delnan - I am trying to refactor/transform some old code for work but the astor/codegen.py file I am using causes drastic changes to the overall format of the code. So I am trying to do a first pass with tokenize to get the original format of the file. Then transofrm the file. Then clean the file up so it looks like the old file ie. 'pretty print' with the new transforms included.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"def\s[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\((.*?)\):"
```